# Is it possible to upload multiple versions of the same package to pypiserver?

Tags: python

Say you have two different versions of the same package and want to upload them to `pypiserver` and have clients install the version they want via `pip`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You just upload package twice setting different version (e.g. first `0.1` and second `0.2`) in `setup.py` of your package.

[Here](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/) is instruction on how to upload.

Then the user can install a specific version using the following command

```
pip install 'package_name==0.1'
```

or

```
pip install 'package_name<=0.1'
```